# yii-queue-worker_01 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

Tags: yii2, freebsd, supervisord

Хочу запустить супервизор. Операционная система FreeBSD.
Для использования очередей в yii2.

Ловлю такую ошибку:

```
 INFO gave up: yii-queue-worker_01 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Вот конфиг

```
[program:yii-queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/vhost/t11.ru/htdocs/php yii queue/listen --verbose=1 --color=0 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/usr/local/www/vhost/t11.ru/logs/yii-queue-worker.log
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Супервайзер говорит о том, что не смог запустить указанную команду. Проверьте что она вообще работает.

Формат команды для запуска воркеров должен выглядеть так:

```
{php} {yii} queue/listen --verbose=1 --color=0
```

где `{php}` - полный путь к php, а `{yii}` - полный путь к консольной точке входа вашего проекта.

Видимо вместо:

```
/usr/local/www/vhost/t11.ru/htdocs/php yii
```

должно быть что-то типа:

```
/usr/local/www/vhost/t11.ru/htdocs/php/yii
```